# Can I load PDF to .NET ReportViewer?

Tags: .net, pdf, reportviewer

Can I load a PDF into a .NET ReportViewer control?  If so, how can I do it?

Best Regards,
Yohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't open a PDF document directly from the ReportViewer.

The ReportViewer loads a [report definition language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee224370.aspx) (RDL) file, and can then output the result in the viewer or export to PDF/Word/HTML etc.

In which environment are you trying to do this?  You can [open and write](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654) a PDF file to the browser directly in ASP.NET by manipulating the Response object.